# Is there a way to update 'self' in a class when running the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a Python class (rotater) whose init function will take in a
>   single additional argument which is a string; an internal variable
>   (store) will be set to that string. There is also a function in this
>   class called evolve which will take in a single additional argument n
>   that specifies how many rotations should be applied to store. E.g., if
>   store was "abed" and evolve(l) was called, then store would be updated
>   to "bcda". If evolve(l) were the called, then store would be "cdab"
>   (from "bcda"). If evolve(2) were then called, then store would be
>   "abed" (from "cdab"). Evolve should both update store, and return the
>   updated value of store.

My code runs perfectly well except that it cannot update the 'self' object in the class 'rotater'. The question asks to update store, and return the updated value of store.

```
class rotater:
    def __init__(self,store):
        self.store=store
    def evolve(self,n):
        shift=self.store[:int(n)]
        new_string=self.store[int(n):]+shift
        store=new_string
        return store
```

I expect after two calls of the function evolve the string will be evolved two times.
But after the first time the instance is still remains the same.

Comment: `self.store = new_string`

Answer (score 1):

```
class rotater:
    def __init__(self,store):
        self.store=store
    def evolve(self,n):
        shift=self.store[:int(n)]
        new_string=self.store[int(n):]+shift
        self.store = new_string
        return new_string
```

This way you redefine the store attribute (To define an attribute, you have to write it in the sintax `self.attribute = value` not `attribute = value`